# Есть ли альтернатива данных свойств или решение сделать текст градиентом?

Tags: html, css, текст, crossbrowsertesting

Попробовал данные свойства и у меня возникли вопросы.

```css
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
-webkit-background-clip: text
```

1. Стоит ли их вообще использовать, если тут требуется префикс `-webkit`, т.е только для поддержки chrome, значит в safari и т.д. не будет поддерживаться?
2. Почему-то данные свойства обрезают некоторые символы, например `g, y, p` половины нижней части просто нет.

Comment: Есть как минимум 4 альтернативы: Тупо каринка || нарисовать на Canvas || нарисовать на SVG || создать пару сотен блоков шириной 1px, в каждом из которых будет тот же текст разного цвета. Если важно сохранить выделяемость текста, можно поверх этого всего натянуть еще один обычный блок текста с transparent текстом.

Comment: @Sevastopol: это ещё что!.. Пробегал вопрос по анимации со ссылкой на сайт. Перешёл, открыл, а там... на каждую анимацию по 100 PNG картинок 300х300 !!! А таких анимаций на странице штуки четыре. Если найду вопрос, то дам ссылку.

Comment: @Sevastopol: ох, нашёл - dgpacker.ru Выглядит красиво тилт-эффект, но ну её нафиг такую реализацию :) С телефона лучше не заходить, так как ошибся я немного - размер картинок там 1024х768 )))

Answer (score 2):

1. Чем Вам префикс не угодил? Все современные браузеры, включая Safari, [поддерживают](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_-webkit-text-fill-color) свойство `text-fill-color` именно с префиксом `-webkit-`.
   То же относится и к `background-clip` со значением `text` - [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/background-img-opts).
2. Свойства эти ничего не обрезают. Скорее всего это какие-то несостыковки в `font-size`, `line-height` и размерами контейнеров, где текст находится. Допускаю, что может таки быть баг со слишком экзотическими шрифтами, но маловероятно.

По поводу альтернатив... Кроме того, что уже перечислили в комментарии под вопросом - `<img>`, `<canvas>`, `<svg>` (кучу `<div>` не рассматриваю в силу отсутствия возможности работать с каким-либо изображением, кроме градиента) - можно поэкспериментировать со свойствами `mix-blend-mode`, `background-blend-mode` и различными фильтрами.

Answer (score 2):

Canvas - как один из вариантов:

```js
(function() {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  var w = canvas.width = 550;
  var h = canvas.height = 300;
  document.getElementById('text').appendChild(canvas);
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.font = "100px Fantasy";
  ctx.textAlign = 'left';
  var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(400, 0, 100, 200);
  gradient.addColorStop(0, "green");
  gradient.addColorStop(1, "red");
  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
  ctx.fillText("Заголовок", h / 10, w / 5);
})();
```

```html
<div id="text" data-text="Заголовок"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

SVG - как один из вариантов:

```css
svg {font-family: fantasy;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="text" x1="80%" x2="0" y1="0" y2="80%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
      <stop stop-color="green" offset="0%"/>
      <stop stop-color="red" offset="100%"/> 
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
    <text fill="url(#text)">
      <tspan font-size="30" x="0" dy="25">Заголовок</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```